# data pager in listview Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a listview where in I placed datapager as follows.
I am using SQl datasource and binding the records to ListView.

```
asp:ListView runat="server" ID="ListView1" DataKeyNames="ProductId,GameName" DataSourceID="GameTable" OnItemCommand="On_Select_Item"
```

and datapager in the LayoutTemplate

And in the item template I am placing a button, when clicked it calls a method where i am trying to fetch DatakeyName values. It is working fine in first page when pager is given, However when moved to other page in the pager, it is throwing me an exception.
Here is the button click code,

```
protected void On_Select_Item(object sender, ListViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {

        if (String.Equals(e.CommandName, "AddtoCart"))
        {
            //checks if the user is logged in
            if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                ListViewDataItem dataItem = (ListViewDataItem)e.Item;
                DropDownList dl = e.Item.FindControl("DropDownList") as DropDownList;
                String val="";

                if (dl != null)
                {
                    val = dl.SelectedValue; //Get the selected value from DropDownList
                }
                String price = Convert.ToString(e.CommandArgument).Trim(); //Get the price for the selected game.
```

-------------Exception is thrown at below line ---------

```
          string ProductId =
            ListView1.DataKeys[dataItem.DataItemIndex]["ProductId"].ToString(); //Product Id for the selected game.
            string GameName = ListView1.DataKeys[dataItem.DataItemIndex]["GameName"].ToString(); //gamename

...............................
.............................
```

}

Comment: What's the exception?

Comment: Any particular reason of using DataPager ? you can use the inbuild paging and sorting feature that comes wiht gridview/listview and by using a sqldatasource (as a data provider to your grid) you need not to do the paging manually, it automatically takes care of the pagin, page index.

Comment: The exception I am getting is ArgumentOutOfRange and I am using datapager because the query is returning multiple records and I will check inbuilt paging and get back to you

Comment: @TwinklingStar sure do let me know in case you need a code spinet I have used the feature many time and it works like a charm.

Comment: @VishalSachdeva Could you please post it.

Answer (score 0):

Define a grid first (you can change the control name to listView but the implementation is the same )

```
 <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="grdResult" 
                    CellPadding="2" 
                    OnPageIndexChanging="grdResult_PageIndexChanging"
                    GridLines="None" 
                    Width="100%" 
                    AllowSorting="True" 
                    AllowPaging="True"
```

Then in the bottom define a data source

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="sqlGridData" runat="server"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

now in the code behind load your sqlGridData control with data (it accepts many parameters like datatable, odbcrecordset you can use .provider property mentioned here http://tinyurl.com/bllyjsz ) if you have static data them you even mention at the design time (as done here http://tinyurl.com/c8b6mbh)

```
private void BindDataGrid()
    {
        sqlGridData.Provider = dataReader;
        grdResult.DataSourceID = "xmlGridData";
        //grdResult.PageIndex = 0;
    }
```

Try this and do let me know if you have any query.

Comment: The problem is with             ListView1.DataKeys[dataItem.DataItemIndex]["ProductId"].ToString(); //Product Id for the selected game.
            string GameName = ListView1.DataKeys[dataItem.DataItemIndex]["GameName"].ToString(); //gamename
I am unable to get the datakey values :(

Comment: @TwinklingStar : Please post your code here and I'll try to look into it (you can edit your orignal post to add the code) and just give a try to parsing instead of casting (just to avoid null validation ) like : string GameName = (string)ListView1.DataKeys[dataItem.DataItemIndex]["GameName"]; or try convert.tostring().